# Removing items while iterating in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have below code block with foreach loop. I want to convert it into the for loop because of we can't modify a collection while we are iterating over it with a foreach loop.

```
 foreach (Price pax_price_entry in entry.Where(o => o.ID == (int)Price.PriceItemID.BookingFee))
                    {
                        //only if it's an "included in booking prices" booking fee price element
                        if (!pax_price_entry.RestrictedIndicator) booking_fees_amount += pax_price_entry.Amount;
                        //remove this price element - it will be re-created if needed
                        entry.Remove(pax_price_entry);
                    }
```

Help me to convert same in For loop.

Comment: How would converting the `foreach` loop to a `for` loop prevent you from modifying the collection while it is iterated?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `for` doesn't force an enumeration of the IEnumerable, thus won't raise an exception. All that's needed is to count from end to start, so index values don't change as iteration progresses

Comment: @Panagiotis, yes, you still have to iterate from end to start (or only increment the index when not removing). My point was that converting into a `for` loop is not a magic bullet in itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just grab the collection and iterate over its count.  Something like this:

```
var pax_price_entries = entry.Where(o => o.ID == (int)Price.PriceItemID.BookingFee).ToList();
for (var i = 0; i < pax_price_entries.Count(); i++)
{
    if (!pax_price_entries[i].RestrictedIndicator)
        booking_fees_amount += pax_price_entries[i].Amount;
    entry.Remove(pax_price_entries[i]);
}
```

Converting to a `for` loop isn't really the most important part.  Materializing the collection into its own list so you can modify the original collection is.

Answer (score 1):

Can i show you a completely different approach using LINQ's [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb549073(v=VS.100).aspx)? You can create a [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx) which contains two groups of entries, those where the ID matches and all others. Then you can use this lookup for all operations:

1.) Create the lookup:

```
var isMatchingID = entry.ToLookup(o => o.ID == (int)Price.PriceItemID.BookingFee);
```

2.) Sum the amount of the matching ID's and `RestrictedIndicator==false`:

```
int booking_fees_amount = isMatchingID[true]
    .Where(o => !o.RestrictedIndicator)
    .Sum(o => o.Amount);
```

3.) Create the list from the non-matching ID entries(your `Remove`):

```
entry = isMatchingID[false].ToList();
```

If you want to keep your old entries assign this to a different variable.